# What is the minUptime

Tags: node.js, daemon, forever

I am using [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) with my project. What do these options do:

- `minUptime`
- `spinSleepTime`

I didn't understand from GitHub page.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Forever's documentation [explains each briefly](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line):

```
--minUptime      Minimum uptime (millis) for a script to not be considered "spinning"
--spinSleepTime  Time to wait (millis) between launches of a spinning script.
```

A "spinning" application is one that keeps failing/crashing shortly after a restart.

`--minUptime` sets the minimum amount of time that an application is expected to run. If it crashes before that limit, it's considered to be "*spinning*" or problematic.

`--spinSleepTime` sets an amount of time that `forever` will wait before trying to restart a "*spinning*" application again.

Collectively, they help prevent having an application rapidly being restarted only to crash each time.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the app from being restarted at all, and/or report that it has crashed too many times? There's a `-m` option, but it doesn't distinguish between spinning crashes and crashes after the application has launched properly.